# Use sfportscan preprocessor in snort 3

Tags: snort

I have not found anywhere how to configure and use `sfportscan` in snort 3; all documentation I can find is for snort 2. I am aware of [this answer,](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33162/snort-ids-dont-show-port-scans) which applies to snort 2.9, and I don't think it helps me here.

As far as I understood, I need to put it into the `stream = {}` object in my `snort.lua` file, but what is the syntax for that? I tried multiple different ways, and all result in errors.

For example: in the documentation [here,](https://www.snort.org/faq/readme-sfportscan) an example configuration is given like this:

`preprocessor flow: stats_interval 0 hash 2 preprocessor sfportscan: proto { all } \ scan_type { all } \ sense_level { low }`

Furthermore, is there any good documentation on how to "detect" portscans through this? I need to set up a rule afterwards in the preprocessor rules, correct?
Right now, I can detect some things that happen when a portscan is done (through community rules), but they do not detect the port scan explicitly:

[image: Snort output against an nmap port scan]

I'm sure there must be a better way to detect them!

I found that in my `snort_defaults.lua` file, there are a few configurations for port scans and that in my `snort.lua` config file, some kind of port scan detection is configured:

`port_scan = default_hi_port_scan`

which refers to the configuration in the defaults. Is this correct?

Comment: One question at a time please. What do you want to know most: how to configure sfportscan or how to detect port scans once you configure it?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I would like to be able to detect port scans like in step 6 in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52411580/how-to-use-snort-to-detect-nmap-default-syn-scan

Comment: I suggest you to install snort 2.9, there are a lot of documentation